# How to populate a form:select and select a default value?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have an edit user form which has textfields(**username, lastname..**) and a select of countries. I'm having problems with this select because i don't know the better way to populate it. I've tried populating with **jquery** with success but i cannot select a default value through **commandName**.

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user" action="registerUser.html">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <spring:message code="app.user.username"/><form:input path="username" /><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error" /><br/>
    <spring:message code="app.user.firstname"/> <form:input type="text" path="firstName" /> <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/><br/>
    <spring:message code="app.user.password"/> <form:input type="password" path="password" /><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/><br/>
    <spring:message code="app.user.repassword"/> <form:input type="password" path="confirmPassword" /><form:errors path="confirmPassword" cssClass="error"/><br/>
    <spring:message code="app.user.email"/> <form:input type="text" path="email" /><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/><br/>
    <spring:message code="app.user.country"/> <form:select path="isoCode" items="${countryList}"/><form:errors path="isoCode" cssClass="error"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form:form>
```

I've take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/), so i've tried with a map but i don't know how to return the data to be accesible in the jsp because in the tutorial uses a SimpleFormController but i wouldn't like to code a SimpleFormController for each form. This is my controller to return the view of the form and i have another to catch the submit.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/editUserForm")
 public String recordUserRequestHandler(ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> referenceData = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> country = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    country.put("US", "United Stated");
    country.put("CHINA", "China");
    country.put("SG", "Singapore");
    country.put("MY", "Malaysia");
    referenceData.put("countryList", country);
    return "EditUserForm";
 }
```

is it possible to pass the referenceData to the jsp to be accessed by the form:select?

```
<spring:message code="app.user.country"/> <form:select path="isoCode" items="${countryList}"/><form:errors path="isoCode" cssClass="error"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you don't need to use hashmap for selects. Personally I use simple List with beans which holds my select options.

public class ListOption {
private String id;
private String name;

```
public ListOption(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public ListOption() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

in your controller

```
List<ListOption> selectOptions = new List<ListOption>();
// add Your options 
selectOptions.add(new ListOption("id","value");
```

then put isoCode object into your model with desired (selected) value then spring will manage to mark the value as selected.

in your jsp

```
 <form:select path="isoCode" items="${countryList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
```

Comment: Very interesting aproach @Josef i will try it. I solved it adding the map to the model data. I'm going to edit my own post with the solution but i will accept your solution as correct because you bothered to response me. Thank you

Comment: it works nice, thank you. Where you place these utilities like List option? because i have others such us a method which adds the root of a json list. I would like to follow good practices

Comment: I am placing it in forms jar but it depends on project structure